# Show web page on ChromeCast device

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

Is it possible to show Web page on ChromeCast device from my application using new Google Play SDK? Is it possible with custom receiver?

Answer (score 0):

It is doable, to some extent. You can have an iframe in your receiver to wrap a web page. If you go down that route, you need to be careful not to violate Google's TOS. In addition, you should first search for similar questions before posting one; this question has been asked a number of times in the past.